# Shopify If Tag does not contain

Tags: shopify, smarty

What's the opposite of `contains` in Shopify Liquid Smarty tags?

I basically want to hide products from **Search page** that has the tag `hideme`

Example code : `{% if product.tags contains 'hideme' %}`. In this I want to use `does not contain` instead of `contains`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The opposite of {% if %} is {% unless %} so your code would change to:

```
{% unless product.tags contains 'hideme' %}
     <blinky> stuff mmm good for cookie monster </blinky>
{% endunless %}
```